# batch: Is there any function for converting %errorlevel% to HResult?

Tags: batch-file

I want to get HResult from %errorlevel%. I tried to install a wrong product key using this command

```
wmic path SoftwareLicensingService WHERE (Version is not null) call InstallProductKey ProductKey='xyz'>nul 2>&1
```

The %errorlevel% now return **-1073418160**. Convert it to hex and add "0x" before it. I got **0xC004F050**

I tried to use this command: `powershell "\"0x{0:X}\" -F %errorlevel%`. But I have `chcp 65001` in the first line. Therefore, my console is not flat after running. Is there anyway to convert from %errorlevel% to HResult without executing Powershell?
[image]

"Xin chào" is a traditional greeting of Vietnamese people

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2261):

```
call cmd /c exit /b -1073418160
echo %=exitcode%
```

Result:

```
C004F050
```

so you probably want:

```
call cmd /c exit /b %errorlevel%
echo 0x%=exitcode%
```

Comment: Yes, without the magic `%=exitcode%` variable it's [a lot of calculation](https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#toHex)